# differentiate i.localhost and localhost

Tags: apache2, ssl

what is the difference between `http://i.localhost and http://localhost.`

reason for asking this question

after installed webmin , i have try to enable SSL from its GUI , but it doesn't worked. after that i am not able to access localhost , but i can access it using `http://i.localhost` also able to access localhost using ip `http://127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost is the name used easily access the the machine from it self without using a public network through the loopback interface.

Its specified in your /etc/hosts file  and pointing to your loopback interface that always has the ip  127.0.0.1

Try pinging i.localhost  .Does it respond with the same ip as the loopback interface? If so there is no difference. Web servers though can use different host names (dns names)  with the same ip to to redirect you to different webpages depending on what address you used to access it and is commonly called [vhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html). This sounds exactly like what webmin is doing.